# using .Last.value in rmarkdown/knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Having and Rmd file with below content:

````
```{r}
data.frame(a=1)
str(.Last.value)
```
````

It renders data.frame but rendering `str(.Last.value)` produces `##  NULL`.
Is there any knitr option or a trick I can use to make it works as expected?
Expected output from the second

```
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ a: num 1
```

Comment: `.Last.value` is the "value of the internal evaluation of a **top-level** R expression". I don't know knitr/Markdown but I suspect the `data.frame` is not being evaluated at top-level.

Comment: @user20637 It is not. `.Last.value` won't work in knitr.

Comment: @Yihui you can put it as answer so I can close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to make `.Last.value` to work.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(render = function(x, ...){
    unlockBinding(".Last.value", .BaseNamespaceEnv)
    assign(".Last.value", x, .BaseNamespaceEnv)
    lockBinding(".Last.value", .BaseNamespaceEnv)
    knitr::knit_print(x, ...)
})
```
````

This piece of code defines a custom render function which binds the output to `.Last.value`.

Though, the above fix is not prefect. The behaviour is a little bit different from the console. For example, in R console

```
> x <- 2
> .Last.value
[1] 2
```

The .Last.value returns the last value even if the previous command is nonvisible. On the other hand, the above hack for `knitr` requires that the result was printed.

````
```{r}
x <- 2
x
.Last.value
```
````

---

*Update*

To fully make `.Last.value` works as in R console, instead, you could consider the following high-risk hack which overwrites `knitr` internal function.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
unlockBinding("knit_handlers", getNamespace("knitr"))
evalq(
  assign(
    "knit_handlers", 
    function(fun, options) {
      if (!is.function(fun)) fun = knit_print
      if (length(formals(fun)) < 2)
        stop("the chunk option 'render' must be a function of the form ",
             "function(x, options) or function(x, ...)")
      merge_list(default_handlers, list(value = function(x, visible) {
        unlockBinding(".Last.value", .BaseNamespaceEnv)
        assign(".Last.value", x, .BaseNamespaceEnv)
        lockBinding(".Last.value", .BaseNamespaceEnv)
        if (visible) fun(x, options = options)
      }))
     }
  ), 
  getNamespace("knitr")
)
lockBinding("knit_handlers", getNamespace("knitr"))
```
````

This overwrites the `knitr` internal function `knit_handlers`, so it subjects to break at anytime.

Answer (score 5):

Because all code chunks are evaluated via `eval()` in **knitr**, the last expression of a code chunk is not a **top-level** R expression, and `.Last.value` will not work for **knitr**.

To make this more clear:

```
x = 1
x  # a top-level expression if typed in the R console
```

By comparison, `x` is no longer a top-level expression in `eval()`:

```
some_internal_knitr_function() {
  # internal code
  eval(parse(text = c('x = 1', 'x')))
  # more internal code
}
```